# Adding JHipster to an already-made application?

Tags: web-applications, jhipster

I know JHipster is primarily for generating new apps, but is there any way to (easily?) integrate JHipster to an already-made app? Or any workarounds?

Thanks!

Comment: Your question lacks many details about your already-made app to get useful answers. Is it a spring boot app? Which authentication system? Which database? which kind of data integration do you want to achieve between both parts? Also what's your level in java/spring programming?

Comment: The app uses Angular right now. We want to be able to easily add the many features that JHipster provides on app generation to our app and were wondering if there is a way to do so without having to start over.

Comment: You answered only on the frontend part.

Comment: @GaëlMarziou From what I can tell, we're using Yarn and no database yet (just using mock data from a JSON). We don't have anything else set up to my knowledge (I'm still pretty new to the team).

Answer (score 0):

As per current available information i can say that it would be very difficult to upgrade **your** application to **Jhipster**.

But what you can do is to create fresh **Jhipster application** and try to fit **your** application in that.